# GCC4.8 Version Suggest to use parentheses around operand of '!'

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying the comparison below.

```
if ((tmp->tskt_pRegP->init & 0x1) ||
(rmppP->portAnnounceRecSMP->rcvdAnnounce &&
((!tsn_ptpP->tsn_ptpRegP->tsn_ptpPortRegP[PortNumber]->portEnable & 0x10000)||
(!tsn_ptpP->tsn_ptpRegP->tsn_ptpPortRegP[PortNumber]->portEnable & 0x20000)||
(!tsn_ptpPortAttrP->asCapable))))
{
tsn_ptpPortAttrP->portAnnounceRecSMP->curr = TEST_RECEIVE_STATE_DISCARD;
}
```

When try to compile it with newer version of gcc 4.8 it is throwing error :

error: suggest parentheses around operand of '!' or change '&' to '&&' or '!' to '~' [-Werror=parentheses]
      ((!tsn_ptpP->tsn_ptpRegP->tsn_ptpPortRegP[PortNumber]->portEnable & 0x10000)||

Can anyone please help me in resolving this?

Comment: Issue is resolved after replacing & with &&. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that's what you want actually, if you take the boolean-and it doesn't really make sense

Comment: I suspect you want to change `!tsn_ptpP->tsn_ptpRegP->tsn_ptpPortRegP[PortNumber]->portEnable & 0x10000` to `!(tsn_ptpP->tsn_ptpRegP->tsn_ptpPortRegP[PortNumber]->portEnable & 0x10000)`, and similarly for the next subexpression.

Comment: In order to resolve the issue correctly, you should describe what you want to achieve with that code. E.g. "LSB of initialState", "bit 13 of portEnable", "bit 14 of portEnable", "full value of rcvdAnnounce", "full value of asCapable" and what you want to do with them. As information_interchange mentioned, none of the three `&` seem meaningfully replaceable with `&&`. The use of `!`, `&&` and `||`however looks questionable, too.

Comment: if you replace & with && the innermost expression will always become true

Comment: It is not specific to GCC 4.8; the current  [GCC 7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/) would also give a warning, and hopefully other compilers (e.g. [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)...) also, at least if you compile with all warnings, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra` as you should always do

Answer (score 2):

In the following:

```
(!tsn_ptpP->tsn_ptpRegP->tsn_ptpPortRegP[PortNumber]->portEnable & 0x10000)
```

`!` has higher precedence than the `&` and is so applied to `tsn_ptpP->tsn_ptpRegP->tsn_ptpPortRegP[PortNumber]->portEnable` if you actually want it to be applied to `tsn_ptpP->tsn_ptpRegP->tsn_ptpPortRegP[PortNumber]->portEnable & 0x10000` you need to enclose that expression in parenthesis:

```
!(tsn_ptpP->tsn_ptpRegP->tsn_ptpPortRegP[PortNumber]->portEnable & 0x10000)
```

Comment: @SoronelHaetier you are right. I have done the change and working as expected. Thanks!